# Animating a short sequence

Tags: c#, animation, xna

I'm writing a game and I would like an explosion animation to run whenever a collision occurs. However the approaches I know how to animate are based on keyboard input. What is the best way to code the method so that when called the animation makes a single pass through all frames then stops?

```
public void Update(GameTime gametime)
  {
    timer += gametime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
       if (timer >= msBetweenFrames)
      {
        timer = 0;
        if (CurrentFrame++ == numberOfFrames - 1)
           CurrentFrame = 0;
          rect.X = CurrentFrame * width;
          rect.Y = 0;
     }
  }

   public void Render(SpriteBatch sb, Vector2 position, Color color)
  {
   sb.Draw(aniTex, position, rect, color, 0, Vector2.Zero, 2.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
 }
```

Comment: Does your code do the job? It looks okay.

Comment: In the Update method of Game1.cs there is the call explosionAnimatio.Update(gameTime); Which runs without error but it loops infinitely. I want a single run over the frames then animation to stop.

Comment: That would appear to be because you loop it (when the current frame reaches the end, you reset it back to 0).

Comment: Yes but this isn't this necessary as the animation need to be 'reset' for the next time an explosion occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is simply the looping issue, you can just remove the bit of code in your update that causes it to loop (the `if (CurrentFrame++ == numberOfFrames - 1) CurrentFrame = 0;`) All you would need to do to get the animation to play again, is set the current frame back to 0 when you want it to play. (To stop it drawing, just only do the draw call when you want it.)

If you're looking for a way to structure it (which is how I initially interpreted your question!) why not have a Animated class which you set up with whatever objects you want animated. Something along the lines of

```
class AnimatedObject
{
    Texture2D texture;
    Rectangle currentRectangle;
    Rectangle frameSize;
    int frameCount;
    int currentFrame;

    bool isRunning;

    public AnimatedObject(Texture2D lTexture, Rectangle lFrameSize, int lFrameCount)
    {
        texture = lTexture;
        frameSize = lFrameSize;
        currentRectangle = lFrameSize;
        currentFrame = 0;
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        isRunning = false;
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        isRunning = true;
    }

    public void Restart()
    {
        currentFrame = 0;
        isRunning = true;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if(isRunning)
        {
            ++currentFrame;
            if(currentFrame == frameCount)
            {
                currentFrame = 0;
            }

            currentRectangle.X = frameSize.Width * currentFrame;
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        if(isRunning)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, currentRectangle, Color.White);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously you can extend this to be more sophisticated (eg using your timers to choose when to move frames etc.

Comment: This is well thought out structure and I think it will help to simplify my code. Thank you for an informative answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the animation, for example, by removing the object with the animation from the game when the animation has finished.

Or otherwise, you could set the `currentFrame` to an illegal value (e.g. -1) when the animation is done, and test for that.

```
public void Update(GameTime gametime)
{
    if (currentFrame >= 0)
    {
        timer += gametime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
        if (timer >= msBetweenFrames)
        {
            timer = 0;
            currentFrame++;
            if (currentFramr >= numberOfFrames - 1)
                currentFrame = -1;
            rect.X = CurrentFrame * width;
            rect.Y = 0;
        }
    }
}

public void Render(SpriteBatch sb, Vector2 position, Color color)
{
    if (currentFrame >= 0)
        sb.Draw(aniTex, position, rect, color, 0, Vector2.Zero, 2.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I found this to be helpful.